# Remapping Left Control <LCTL> in xkb changes behavior of Alt + Left Shift

Tags: x11, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

For some reason pressing any alt key (including `<MENU>`) together with `<LFSH>` toggles "Switch windows of an application". This can be turned off by commenting out

```
 key <LCTL> { [    Tab,      Tab,       Tab,         Tab  ] };
```

in my xkb layout file. However, I would like to keep remapping left control `<LCTL>` to `Tab`. How can I do this without causing the above behavior?

I am using Fedora 20 with kernel `3.14.7-200.fc20.i686`.

The corresponding entry in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` is

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "workman-d" {

    name[Group1]= "English (Workman special)";

    include "us(workman)"

    key <TLDE> { [ grave, asciitilde,        degree,           degree ] };
    key <AE03> { [     3, numbersign,       section,          section ] };

    key <TAB> { [    BackSpace,       BackSpace,       BackSpace,        BackSpace ] };
    key <AD01> { [     q,          Q,            at,               at ] };
    key <AD08> { [     u,          U,    udiaeresis,       Udiaeresis ] };

    key <CAPS> { [    Control_L,       Control_L,       Control_L,        Control_L ] };
    key <AC01> { [     a,          A,    adiaeresis,       Adiaeresis ] };
    key <AC02> { [     s,          S,        ssharp,           ssharp ] };
    key <AC08> { [     e,          E,      EuroSign,         EuroSign ] };
    key <AC09> { [     o,          O,    odiaeresis,       Odiaeresis ] };

    key <AB04> { [     c,          C,          cent,        copyright ] };

    key <LCTL> { [    Tab,   Tab,       Tab,         Tab  ] };
    key <LFSH> { [ Shift_L,     Shift_L,      Shift_L,        Shift_L ] };
    key <MENU> { [ Alt_R,      Alt_R,         Alt_R,            Alt_R ] };

};
```

The xev output is

- `keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L)` from pressing left alt
- `keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L)` from pressing left shift
- `FocusOut event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2a00001,
  mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor` from pressing left alt + left shift